# How to use child_process to execute multi commands?

Tags: node.js

I want to use spawn to execute like

```
  cd ../ && ls
```

I tried

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
spawn('cd', ['../', '&&', 'ls'], {
    stdio: 'inherit',
});
```

But failed with:

```
Error: spawn cd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I've googled for this problem for a while, but got no good idea, please help me...

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is a shell operator. In order to use it, you'll need to specify `shell: true` when spawning, and have the entire "chain" as a command, not as arguments:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
spawn('cd .. && ls', {
    shell: true,
    stdio: 'inherit',
});
```